# Flutter App Build apk errors but running is correctly Solved

Tags: flutter, build, icons, apk, build-error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> AAPT: D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
> D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> AAPT: D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
> D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

```
  > Android resource compilation failed
    AAPT: D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
    D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> AAPT: D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
> D:\Flutter Error Project\musicapp\medicos\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Is With APP ICON .

> MAKE APP ICON .PNG FORMAT

Answer (score 0):

**The Error is solved**

**If this type of error occurs it means that your flutter app icon is not png format. So, first, make your app icon in png extension and then again add in your flutter project. This error will be solved.**